# How to connect to firebase database when android device is restarted

Tags: java, android, firebase

so I have what may be a simple problem. I want to connect to my firebase database and listen for any changes so I can show a notification to the user, like for example, you reboot your phone and do not have to open an app, but you can still receive notifications from the app like when a chat comes in. I tried the boot completed receiver but it didn't really work, and I can't seem to get the network change receiver to work when the device is restarted. I have the code to access my database and show notifications. I just need a way to invoke the service that accesses the database and shows notification regardless of whether the device was rebooted or not.
I am using java.
Thanks a lot

Tried boot completed receiver, didn't work, guess due to android changes from Android 8 or 10.
Tried network connection receiver, didn't work when device is rebooted

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please edit your question and add the code that doesn't work the way you expect.

Comment: Aside from that, if you understand Kotlin, I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-use-firebase-cloud-messaging-on-android-d92cb4b53cfe) will help. Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirebaseCloudMessaging).